# How do you build Lua with Dev-C++ compiler?

Tags: c, windows, build, lua, dev-c++

I've been coding in C for a while and I only compiled and debugged with Dev-C++ compiler. Now I'm trying to learn Lua programming language. Just downloaded the Lua source code and I want to compile it with Dev-C++. Can you explain how can I use them? My OS is Win 7.

Edit: Sorry for the explaining mistake. I downloaded the [original Lua source code](http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.4.0.tar.gz) and I want to use the header files that the original source code contains. So I do not know how to add header files to the project that you can open in Dev-C++.

Comment: Do you want to build Lua executable (lua.exe) from sources? Or do you want to run a Lua program? (Did I correctly edit your question?)

Comment: The referred source code is lua-5.4.0.tar.gz from Lua's website. That file contains 'src' directory and it includes a lot of .c and .h files. My first goal is write and run Lua programs with Dev-C++.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you download and use the IDE called [SciTE](https://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html), it is as simple as DEV C++ and comes with a compiler ready to run Lua.

But if you really want to customize a lua compiler, you can call `lua.exe` to compile and run your Lua file

for example, my Lua is installed in `C:\Lua`

so I use the following command to compile my codes:

```
C:\Lua\lua.exe myScript.lua
```

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll check it out. Thanks.